# Capybara feature test (js: true, React) fails because image element forced to make request

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, paperclip, poltergeist

I have a form page that renders react components. These components render images that have been uploaded to the local environment (normally they are uploaded to s3).

Originally, I setup my test environment path to point to inside my spec folder (as advised in the paperclip documentation):
```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] =
    "#{Rails.root}/spec/test_files/:class/:id_partition/:style.:extension"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] =
    "#{Rails.root}/spec/test_files/:class/:id_partition/:style.:extension"

When capybara visits a page with the components, the page gets rendered properly if I remove the `img` element from the component, but if I include the `img` element, a request is made to the server based on the value specified in the image source field. The above path and url aren't public, so this causes a routing exception and my test fails. If I change `spec` to `public`, it works.

If the image is not actually being rendered, why does react/capybara/phantomjs make the request? Is there a way I can configure this stack to not make requests to the image source (for example, if I just wanted to just dummy values)?

Stack:
Rails 4
React
Capybara
Phantomjs
Poltergesit
Rspec
Paperclip